How to implement `map` using the fish (>=>, Kleisli composition) operator in F#?
I'm learning monadic composition through Scott Wlaschin's Railway-oriented Programming post. Oncebind, switch, and >=> functions are defined, he introduces map to show how to "turn a one-track function into a two-track function". That is:
f: a -> b     =>    f': T<a,c> -> T<b,c>

The implementation in the article is the following:
let map oneTrackFunction twoTrackInput =
    match twoTrackInput with
    | Success s -> Success (oneTrackFunction s)
    | Failure f -> Failure f

Did an an equivalent implementation using switch and bind as an exercise,
let map' f = bind (switch f)

but when I tried to implement map with >=>, I arrived at this ugly mess:
let map'' f result =
    match result with
        | Ok o -> ((fun _ -> result) >=> (switch f)) o
        | Error e -> Error e

Note to self: o could be any value of type 'a (if result : Result<'a,'c>), because f's input is already saved in the closure used as >=>'s first operand, but this was the only way I could think of to keep it more generic.
Is there a "cleaner" implementation similar to map's?

Notes
I used the following example to test the maps above:
map  ((+) 2) ((Ok 27) : Result<int,string>)

Used implementations of bind, switch, and >=>:
let bind
    (     f : 'a -> Result<'b,'c>)
    (result :       Result<'a,'c>)
    =
    match result with 
   |    Ok o -> f o
   | Error e -> Error e

let switch
   (f : 'a -> 'b)
   (x : 'a      )
   =
   f x |> Ok

let (>=>)
    (f : 'a -> Result<'b,'error>)
    (g : 'b -> Result<'c,'error>)
    =
    f >> (bind g)


Referring to German wikipedia with examples in Haskell, there are three ways to define the set of monadic operators: either with

fmap and join,
return and >>=, or
return and >=>.

Since you have the Kleisli operator already and want to derive map from it, you only need return (which is Ok here) for this:
let fmap f = id >=> (Ok << f)
// val fmap : f:('a -> 'b) -> (Result<'a,'c> -> Result<'b,'c>)

F# code for the three alternatives:
module Result1 =
    // Definition by fmap and join
    let fmap = Result.map
    let join mma = Result.bind id mma
    // derived:
    let (>>=) ma f = (join << fmap f) ma 
    let (>=>) f g = join << fmap g << f

module Result2  =
    // Definition by return and >>=
    let ``return`` = Ok
    let (>>=) ma f = Result.bind f ma
    // derived:
    let (>=>) f g a = f a >>= g
    let fmap f ma = ma >>= (``return`` << f)
    let join mma = mma >>= id

module Result3  =
    // Definition by return and >=>
    let ``return`` = Ok
    let (>=>) f g a = Result.bind g (f a)
    // derived:
    let (>>=) ma f = (id >=> f) ma
    let fmap f = id >=> (``return`` << f)
    let join mma = (id >=> id) mma


That wiki page is a gold mine, thank you! Will have to brush up on my German, because I haven't found such a collection is English pages yet. (By the way, I already got stuck understanding why id works in the definition of fmap, so here's another question if you are interested.)

I don't think there's a really elegant way to do this. The fish operator composes two "elevated" functions, while the map function applies a plain function to an elevated value. So, to make this work, we need to create two elevated functions from our one plain function, like this:
let map'' f result =
    match result with
        | Ok o ->
            let f' = f >> Ok    // first elevated function
            let g' = id >> Ok   // second elevated function (no-op)
            (f' >=> g') o
        | Error e -> Error e

Which can be simplified to:
let map'' f = function
    | Ok o -> ((f >> Ok) >=> Ok) o
    | Error e -> Error e

(I used a pattern matching function to get rid of the explicit result argument altogether.)
Note that >=> is doing nothing useful here, since the second elevated function is essentially just identity, so we could actually simplify further to:
let map'' f = function
    | Ok o -> (f >> Ok) o
    | Error e -> Error e

Which is just the normal map function.
Another way to think about this is that any elevated function, f', is equivalent to f' >=> Ok, so the "happy" path for map can be written (f >> Ok) >=> Ok, where f is the unelevated version of f'.

@kaefer provided the answer I was looking for, but thank you for all these variations, because I haven't even gotten this far!
